# RabbitMQ - Tls Connection - Golang

Tags: ssl, go, rabbitmq

I configured RabbitMQ connection using follow link:
https://github.com/streadway/amqp/blob/master/examples_test.go

Certificate I created according to the instructions here:
https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html#enabling-tls-paths

I use RabbitMQ 3.7.0 installed in docker.
After the call amqp.DialTLS I receive "Bad certificate" error on the server side (in the docker logs).

I suppose that the problem is that certificate should contain the server name and if so, which server name should I set in the certificate if RabbitMQ is installed inside docker?

Besides, any other ideas?

Comment: Start here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/troubleshooting-ssl.html

Answer (score 4):

I solved this issue by adding to the hosts file full_machine_name from the connection string to RabbitMQ with appropriate IP address: amqps://connection_string_to_RabbitMQ@full_machine_name:5671